# Data Binding on a User Control

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a user control that has a Title property bound to the Text property of a TextBlock:

XAML

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=me,Path=Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Code behind

```
public String Title
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(String), typeof(ClosableTabHeader), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

And I wish to bind this Title property to another property on the main window:

XAML

```
<my:ClosableTabHeader Title="{Binding ElementName=me,Path=ShortenAmount}" />
```

Code behind

```
public Int32 ShortenAmount
{
    get { return (Int32)GetValue(ShortenAmountProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShortenAmountProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShortenAmountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShortenAmount", typeof(Int32), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

However, the textblock does not update.

When I replace the usercontrol declaration with a TextBlock, however, it works fine:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=me,Path=ShortenAmount}" />
```

While there are certainly workarounds, in terms of what I am trying to do itself, may I know where I went wrong?

Comment: Where is the code that contains x:Name=me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in your `ElementName`. From your code `my:ClosableTabHeader` is **not named** as `me`. `me` looks like your `MainWindow`. But you are using `me` and `Title` together in this binding...

```
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=me,Path=Title}"  
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

where `Title` is property from `ClosableTabHeader` and not `MainWindow` (well `MainWindow.Title` exists as a inbuilt WPF property but I am sure we are not talking about it)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The problem was that I had named both the CloseableTabHeader and the MainWindow as "me". I did not know that by declaring a CloseableTabHeader in the MainWindow a name conflict would occur on "me", even code inside CloseableTabHeader. While this answers my question, doesn't this mean that WPF code is a lot less flexible (since one must ensure that all controls have a different name)?

Comment: Its not about being flexible but following the norms of XML in general. **Namescoping** is strict in XML domain. Hence XAML too follows it religiously... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx... and same named elements may exist in a visual tree considering that their scope is abstracted from each other.